# Who signed the 1982 Chicago Statement on Biblical Hermeneutics?

Tags: exegesis, resource-request, evangelicalism, inerrancy

From the [official repository of the International Council on Biblical Inerrancy (ICBI)](https://library.dts.edu/Pages/TL/Special/ICBI.shtml) we can see [the list signers](https://library.dts.edu/Pages/TL/Special/ICBI_1_typed.pdf) for the [1978 Chicago Statement on Biblical Inerrancy](https://library.dts.edu/Pages/TL/Special/ICBI-1978-11-07.pdf) out of over 300 who attended Summit I on Oct 26-28, 1978.

But there is no mention of signers for the [1982 Chicago Statement on Biblical Hermeneutics](https://library.dts.edu/Pages/TL/Special/ICBI_2.pdf) although the [repository homepage](https://library.dts.edu/Pages/TL/Special/ICBI.shtml) said "approximately one hundred people attended [Summit II] and adopted [the statement]".  The 1984 book [Hermeneutics, Inerrancy, and the Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0310370817), containing papers presented at Summit II, the statement, and other materials, does **not** contain a list of signers either.  Nor is it mentioned in the related [*Wikipedia* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Statement_on_Biblical_Inerrancy).

The question: **Who signed the 1982 Chicago Statement on Biblical Hermeneutics?**

I think the question is important since the Biblical Hermeneutics statement places more restriction on how the Chicago doctrine of Inerrancy is applied to Evangelical exegesis, especially with regards to Genesis 1-11 (Article XXII).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emailed library@dts.edu (owner/source of articles from OP) asking for signatures and this is the response

> List of Signatures for the ICBI Chicago Statement on Biblical Hermeneutics, 1982
> (The typed list found in the collection was incomplete. This list was compiled by Lolana Thompson, and might contain errors due to illegible writing, typographical errors, or omissions. 3/25/2009)

- Allen, Ronald B.
- Archer, Gleason L.
- Barker, Kenneth L.
- Beck, W. David
- Bell, W. [William] E., Jr.
- Boice, James M.
- Borror, James A.
- Bradley, Walter L.
- Capper, LeRoy S.
- Caster, Dick
- Clowney, Edmund P.
- Clutter, Ronald T.
- Congdon, James R.
- Corduan, Winifred
- Davis, John J.
- Dayton, Wilber T.
- DeVries, Robert K.
- Dockery, David S.
- Douglass, David R.
- Drescher, Charles Daniel
- Ecklebarger, Kermit A.
- Erickson. Millard
- Feinberg, Charles Lee
- Feinberg, John S.
- Feinberg, Paul D.
- Gardner, Lynn
- Geisler, Norman L.
- Grimstead, Jay
- Grudem, Wayne A.
- Gruenler, Royce G.
- Gundry, Stanley N.
- Hanna, Mark M.
- Hare, George W.
- Helm, Paul
- Henry, Carl F. H.
- Hesselgrave, David J.
- Hoehner, Harold W.
- Hoke, Donald E.
- Hoyt, Karen
- Inch, Morris
- Jenson, Ronald A.
- Johnson, Alan F.
- Johnson, Elliott
- Johnson, John F.
- Johnson, Paul C.
- Johnson, S. Lewis, Jr.
- Kelbey, David B.
- Kerr, Eugene G.
- Kik, Frank N.
- Klooster, Fred H.
- Knevel, Andries
- Knight, George W., III
- Krabbendam, Henry
- Kuhn, Harold B.
- Kullenz (or perhaps Kulleny), S.
- Lewis, Gordon R.
- Lindsell, Harold
- Lindsley, Arthur
- Lutzer, Erwin W.
- MacArthur, John
- MacRae, Allan A.
- Marquart, Kurt
- Mayhue, Richard L.
- McBride, Betty
- McCarthy, Daryl E.
- McDowell, Josh D.
- McQuilkin, Robertson
- Mitchell, Daniel R.
- Moeller, Reinhard
- Moreland, J. [James] P.
- Morgan, Brian G.
- Nicole, Roger
- Orr, Robert D.
- Ortlund, Raymond C.
- Osborne, Grant
- Packer James I.
- Palau, Luis
- Patterson, Paige
- Payne, Ed [Franklin Ed, Jr.]
- Pement, Eric N.
- Phillips, W. Gary
- Poythress, Vern S.
- Preus, Robert
- Radmacher, Earl D.
- Ramsey, Christopher J.
- Rawley, Philip E.
- Reed, Jeff R.
- Richter, Bryan H.
- Robinson, Haddon W.
- Rogers, Adrian
- Saucy, Robert L.
- Scaer, David P.
- Scharfe, Ronald C.
- Schatz, Frederic R.
- Shackleford, Karen R.
- Smith, Morton (? H.)
- Smith, Robert W.
- Stevens, Ronnie Collier
- Sutcliffe, Harry J.
- Taylor, G. Aiken
- Udd, Stan
- Uenuma, Masao
- Wacker, Frederick G., (? Jr.)
- Walker, Larry L.
- Walt, John
- Walvoord, John F.
- Weber, S. K.
- Whitlock, Luder G.
- Wilkinson, Bruce H.
- Youngblood, Ronald
- Zuck, Roy B.

Comment: Wow, out of the box thinking :-).  Also impressed on how fast they respond.  Maybe they often received that query.  Hopefully one day they update their repository home page, even though it's incomplete.